# Gif image is not working in chrome, but working in firefox and ie

Tags: html, google-chrome, animated-gif

I have included a gif image in my html

```
<div id="overlay-inAbox8">
  <div class="wrapper" id="overlay-inAbox8wrapper">
    <img id="loading-gif" src="{% static 'loading.gif' %}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#loading-gif{
    width:100%;
}

#overlay-inAbox .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
#overlay-shade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #000;
}

.overlay {
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #000;
} 
.ie7 .overlay {
    height: 200px;
}
 .overlay .wrapper {
padding: 15px 30px 30px;
text-align: center;
}

#overlay-inAbox8 {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 190px;
   height: 90px;
   line-height: 90px;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: -100px;
   display: none;
}
```

The animated gif is getting displayed as an static image in Chrome, but displayed correctly in Firefox and ie.

When I try to display just the gif in chrome, it works fine.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with CSS but rather with this interesting looking link you have: src="{% static 'loading.gif' %}"

Comment: @RachelS it's a django template so the path is specified like this. It's getting rendered correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your value for auto repeat for both firefox and chrome.....
By default for firefox: auto repeat "on".
By default for firefox: auto repeat "off".